# HTML div height gets half when exported to pdf or print

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have a div (with id 'receipt'). For testing I did some coloring to understand the rendering of the contents.

[image]

[image]

The problem is, when I do exporting to pdf or print the receipt, the height of the content gets spliced and half of the page get blank.

[image]

[image]

I have used angularjs. Below is the code block of the receipt.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inline" ng-click="vm.back()"><</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inline" ng-click="vm.print()">Print</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inline" ng-click="vm.downloadPdf('receipt')">Pdf</button>
<div class="container-fluid" id="receipt" style="background: white">
    <style type="text/css">
        .invoice-title h2, .invoice-title h3 {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .table > tbody > tr > .no-line {
            border-top: none;
        }

        .table > thead > tr > .no-line {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .table > tbody > tr > .thick-line {
            border-top: 2px solid;
        }

        .white-border-color {
            border-color: white
        }
    </style>

    <div class="box-typical box-typical-padding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-12">
                <!--<div class="row text-center">
                    <h5>
                        <strong>
                            <label class="text-center">
                                Invoice/Bill:
                            </label>
                        </strong>
                    </h5>
                </div>-->
                <div class="row text-center" ng-hide="true">
                    <label class="text-center" style="color: darkgray;">
                        Printed on {{vm.today | date}} from BizBook365, proudly developed by Code Coopers
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 20px">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <img ng-src="{{vm.model.shop.logoUrl}}" style="height:100px;width:100px" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                            <br />
                            <br />


                            <address class="ng-binding">
                                Order # <strong>{{vm.model.orderNumber}}</strong>
                                {{vm.model.orderDate | date}}<br>
                                <strong>{{vm.model.orderReferenceNumber}}</strong>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <address>
                                <strong>Billed To:</strong><br>
                                {{vm.model.customerName}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.customerPhone}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.address.streetAddress}}<br />

                                <!--{{vm.model.address.addressName}}<br />-->
                                {{vm.model.address.area}} {{vm.model.address.thana}} {{vm.model.address.district}}<br />
                                l.
                                <strong>Note:</strong><br />
                                {{vm.model.customerNote}}<br />
                                Customer Total Due:<strong>( {{vm.model.customer.totalDue}} )</strong>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                            <address>
                                <strong>{{vm.model.shop.name}}</strong><br>
                                {{vm.model.shop.streetAddress}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.shop.area}},{{vm.model.shop.thana}},{{vm.model.shop.postCode}},{{vm.model.shop.district}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.shop.website}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.shop.facebook}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.shop.email}}<br />
                                {{vm.model.shop.phone}}<br />
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default white-border-color">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">Order summary</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-condensed">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><strong>Item</strong></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><strong>Price</strong></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                                            <td class="text-right"><strong>Totals</strong></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="p in vm.model.saleDetails track by $index" ng-hide="p.isReturned" ng-if="p.quantity>0">
                                            <td>{{p.productDetailName}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{p.salePricePerUnit}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{p.quantity}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-right">{{p.total}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="thick-line"><strong>Product Total</strong></td>
                                            <td class="thick-line"></td>
                                            <td class="thick-line"></td>
                                            <td class="thick-line text-right">{{vm.model.productAmount}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Delivery Charge</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{vm.model.shippingAmount}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{vm.model.totalAmount}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Discount</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{vm.model.discountAmount}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Payable</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{vm.model.payableTotalAmount}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Paid</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right"><strong>{{vm.model.paidAmount}}</strong></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="no-line"><strong>Due</strong></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                                            <td class="no-line text-right"><strong>{{vm.model.dueAmount}}</strong></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It gets render by the below way
[image]

The red-ish color causes the extra space in the bottom of the page.

Comment: What library are you using to create the PDF? That's probably where your problem lies. If it's rendering correctly on the page, there's not much anyone here can do to help.

Comment: Its not about the pdf library. check the edited question please. thanks

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Personally, I hate trying to render a web page to a PDF. I'd rather just take the values and inject them in to a PDF I have more control over. I've used TCPDF extensively. But that requires a lot of PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

use Jasper reports. It's most easy to create PDF

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).